# How to enumerate columns in Spark's DataFrame? What if columns are nested?

Tags: python, apache-spark, mariadb, spark-streaming

Apperently it doesn't have `items()` method. By how then?

I am trying to send Row to database with the code:

```
def write_row(table_name, cur, row):
    data = []
    for key, value in row.items():
        data.append((key, value))
    data = zip(*data)

    columns = ", ".join(data[0])
    values = data[1]
    questionmarks = ", ".join(["?"] * len(columns))

    query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({columns}) VALUES ({questionmarks})"
    cur.execute(query, values)


def write_data_frame(df, epoch1):
    conn = mariadb.connect(**config["mariadb"])
    cur = conn.cursor()

    table_name = "pysparktest"

    rows = df.collect()
    for row in rows:
        write_row(table_name, cur, row)

    conn.commit()
```

It swears

```
AttributeError: items
```

What if rows are nested?

```
root
 |-- track: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- car: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cnt: long (nullable = false)
 |-- minBestLapTime: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: try `row.asDict().items()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the compiler swears - there is no method called "items()" in Row class.

What you need to do is use "asDict" method. It outputs key, values in Row as python dict.

In the case of nested columns, there is an argument in asDict function called recursive, set that to True. By default, it is set as False.

For instance:

```
row = Row(name="Alice", age=11)
row_as_dict = row.asDict()
row_as_dict
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 11}
```

For iterating:

```
for key in row_as_dict:
    print("{} : {}".format(key, row_as_dict[key]))
```

Output:

```
name : Alice
age : 11
```

In case of nested columns

```
row = Row(key=1, value=Row(name='a', age=2))
row_as_dict = row.asDict(recursive=True)
row_as_dict
```

Output:

```
{'key': 1, 'value': {'name': 'a', 'age': 2}}
```